# Arc length ( Just checking if i am right)

Tags: calculus

Consider the curve $y=x^{2/3}$:

a. Sketch the curve between $x=-1$ and $x=8$. ( I sketched it already)

b. Explain why the formula 
$$
\int_{-1}^{8}\,\sqrt{1+ \left({\rm d}y \over {\rm d}x\right)^{2}\,}\,\,{\rm d}x
$$
cannot be used to find arc length of the curve sketched. because
$\displaystyle{{{\rm d}y \over {\rm d}x} = {2 \over 3x^{1/3}}}$. Therefore, is undefined at $x=0$.

c. Find the arc length of the curve. 
Solve for $x$, $x=y^{3/2}$, and use the arc length with $y$ bounds which are from $1$ to $4$.

Comment: It's an $\large\tt\mbox{integrable singularity}$. It goes $\large\tt\sim x^{-1/3}$ when $\large x \sim 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Derivative $x'=\frac{3}{2}y^{0.5}$, square it to get $\frac{9y}{4}$. Put in arc length formula to get $(1+\frac{9y}{4})^{0.5}$. Now integrate to obtain $\frac{4}{9}*\frac{2}{3}(1+\frac{9y}{4})^{1.5}$ running from 1 till 4. Can you finish it now?